# Issue with storing values of Multiselect in database

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-multiselect

Alright I have a hell of a problem right now .

I have a bootstrap multiselect like below which allows me to add or remove groups for an user.

[image]

Well it works but there is a bug which remove me 1 additional group each time I click on `"Submit"`

Example : If the user was in 3 groups( `blabla, bleble and blibli`) and I press `Submit` without even touching the groups, it will remove the user from 1 group and he will have only 2 left (`blabla and bleble`).

Here is the `PHP` code i used for treatement :

```
$groupes = $_GET['groupes'];
$idc = $_GET['idc'];
if ($groupes != "null") {
    $g = explode(',', $groupes);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($g); $i++) {

        $sqlDel = "DELETE FROM appartenir  WHERE idc = $idc";

        $reqDel = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlDel) or die('Erreur SQL !<br/>' . $sqlDel . '<br/>' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($g); $i++) {
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO appartenir(idc,idg) VALUES('$idc', '$g[$i]')";
        $req1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql1) or die('Erreur SQL !<br/>' . $sql1 . '<br/>' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
    }

}
```

And the `HTML`code of the select if it helps :

```
 <select id="filtreMultiselectModif" name="groupes[]" multiple="multiple">

              <?php

            while ($data3 = mysqli_fetch_array($req3)) { // Remplissage du SELECT
                $idg = $data3['idg'];
                $intitule = $data3['intitule'];
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $idg ?>" selected><?php echo $intitule ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php


            while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($req2)) { // Remplissage du SELECT
                $idg = $data2['idg'];
                $intitule = $data2['intitule'];
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $idg ?>"><?php echo $intitule ?></option>
            <?php } ?>

        </select>
```

I don't think putting the jquery code will be useful

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: For starters, there's a missing comma in your first snippet (2nd line). Please post your code without syntax errors. Thanks.

Comment: @ar27111994 Yeah I wrote this line manually and forgot it, but the code has no syntax  errors otherwhise

Comment: Check the ids in value attribute of option tags, whether they are being properly rendered or not? Also, why are you using two different variables idc and groupes in first snippet. Please explain your code more thoroughly.

Comment: @ar27111994 Yeah the id are well rendered. So actually idc stands for the id of the user and idg is the id of his group(s), and appartenir is an associative table which tell which user is in which groups. Sorry if it wasn't clear enough

Comment: Another question, why are you using get method instead of post for submitting selected groups? Can you try using form method = "post"?

Comment: And in that case you don't need to use explode either.

Comment: Oh and you also have first option selected by default. Maybe that's causing the error.

Comment: @ar27111994 Well i don't know how to use the Post method in jquery :( this is a really weird think. But GET method should be working aswell , no ? ?

Comment: @ar27111994 Yeah the first option are actually the groups who are already affected to the user so they are selected by default. And the second option are the rest of the groups

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120491/discussion-between-ar27111994-and-developpeurduturfu).